# Multiple Checkboxes in Angular

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

Trying to implement multiple `<input />` fields, that populate `<div>` elements with the text entered. After those are implemented, I want to implement a set of `<input class="checkbox">` that when clicked will wrap the input text in additional text, depending on the checkbox selected.

The problem is the 1st `checkbox` is bound to the second `checkbox`. How do I separate the model associated with each checkbox?

I am currently using ng-switch-when and trying to set the values in the controller, but it's failing to bind separately as per the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ch6hf7rbyiEtaVo2qyq9?p=preview)

```
<div class="code alert-box warning" ng-switch on="TrackingCode.AddOnClick">
<div ng-switch-when="true">
    <!-- code to render when AddOnClick checkbox is checked-->
    <code>
        onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent({{category}}', '{{action}}', '{{label}}', '{{value}}', '{{nonInteraction}}']);"
    </code>
</div>
<div ng-switch-when="test">
    <!-- code to render when Something Else checkbox is checked-->
    <code>
        SomethingElse="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent({{category}}', '{{action}}', '{{label}}', '{{value}}', '{{nonInteraction}}']);"
    </code>
</div>
<div ng-switch-default>
    <!-- code to render when AddOnClick checkbox is un-checked -->
    <code>
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '{{category}}', '{{action}}', '{{label}}', '{{value}}', '{{nonInteraction}}']);
    </code>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You assign the same model to both checkboxes, so they show the same values. Seems you are looking for radio buttons, at least in functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can simplify your `OnClickCheckbox()` function to:

```
 /* Wrap output in onclick function */
$scope.OnClickCheckbox = function () 
    $scope.AddOnClick = !($scope.AddOnClick);
}
```

Secondly, you lack a `UniversalGACheckbox()` function, which you are assigning to your second checkbox `ng-click`.

Third, if you are assigning an `ng-switch-when=test`, that will never happen if you are binding to a value that only alternates between `true` and `false`, that state will never be reached.

You need to separate your checkboxes so that they are not bound to the same `true/false` `$scope` variable, although I think there is probably a better way to do this, a quick fix would be something like:

```
<div class="code alert-box warning" ng-switch on="TrackingCode.AddOnClick">

                <div ng-switch-when="true">
                    <!-- code to render when AddOnClick checkbox is checked-->
                    <code>
                    onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent({{category}}', '{{action}}', '{{label}}', '{{value}}', '{{nonInteraction}}']);"
                    </code>            
                </div>
                <div ng-switch-default>
                    <!-- code to render when AddOnClick checkbox is un-checked -->
                    <code>
                    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '{{category}}', '{{action}}', '{{label}}', '{{value}}', '{{nonInteraction}}']);
                    </code>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="code alert-box warning" ng-switch on="TrackingCode.AddOnClick2">
              <div ng-switch-when="true">
                    <!-- code to render when AddOnClick checkbox is checked-->
                    <code>
                    SomethingElse="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent({{category}}', '{{action}}', '{{label}}', '{{value}}', '{{nonInteraction}}']);"
                    </code>            
                </div>
                <div ng-switch-default>
                    <!-- code to render when AddOnClick checkbox is un-checked -->
                    <code>
                    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', '{{category}}', '{{action}}', '{{label}}', '{{value}}', '{{nonInteraction}}']);
                    </code>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And in your script:

```
/* Wrap output in onclick function */
    $scope.OnClickCheckbox = function () {

        $scope.AddOnClick = !($scope.AddOnClick);
    }

    $scope.UniversalGACheckbox = function(){
      $scope.AddOnClick2 = !($scope.AddOnClick2);
    }
```

However, this is bad coding style, and involves a lot of duplication

Comment: Thanks, I never thought about duplicating the HTML - get that it's bad practice but I'm just keen to get this working and can tidy it up later when I understand this stuff a bit more. Will use ng-show to control the display of those duplicated divs.